# Symfony2, RabbitMQ and Redis throttling

Tags: symfony, redis, rabbitmq, throttling

I'm trying to implement rate limits on my client side api calls. Since there are about 20 Symfony2 commands that use the same api(limited to 10 reqs/sec) every 15 minutes i needed to use RabbitMQ so my processes wouldn't run out of memory or prevent next ones to execute properly.

Since api calls are executed in commands and RabbitMQ workers i need to throttle them in RabbitMQ, too. I'm aware that workers shouldn't do that kind of work in my case but i have no time to refactor the whole thing.

So, is it possible to throttle the method that is common for all of those commands in my RabbitMQ workers? I'm trying with https://github.com/jaytaph/RateLimitBundle and https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle (with predis library and Redis installed and running on my system) but i'm kind of stuck.

How should i handle the case when rate limit approaches the maximum? Do i need an event listener? Do i have to check for rate limits from Redis and if it's close engage throttling?

My method looks like this

```
    /**
     * @RateLimit(limit=10, period=60)
     */
    protected function apiRequest($query)
    {
        $url = $this->getApiUrl().$query.$this->getUsernameAndApiKey();

        echo $url. "\r\n";

        $xml = $this->getWithCurl($url);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

//            if ($xml === false) {
//                $this->slack->sendMessage($this->getError($url));
//            }

        if($xml)
            return $xml;

    }
```

Redis config:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
```

Rate limit config:

```
noxlogic_rate_limit:
    enabled:    true
    storage_engine: "redis"
    redis_client:   default
    rate_response_code: 429
    rate_response_exception:    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\TooManyRequestsHttpException
    display_headers:    true
    headers:
        limit:  X-RateLimit-Limit
        remaining:  X-RateLimit-Remaining
        reset:  X-RateLimit-Reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `INCRBY` Redis command (https://redis.io/commands/incrby). The response from the command will be value after increment, so in code you can compare this value with your limit like this:

```
$counter = $redis->increment($key);
if ($counter > $limit) {
    //deny logic here
}
```

It will work with many simultaneous requests being processed because of single-thread atomic nature of Redis, so no more than $limit requests will be processed.